# No Such table for Sqlite Existing Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want use existing sqlite database in my app to get user address details.Database Connections all working fine.but always showing "no such table" error message.i have checked the database in sqlite manager.It has pincode table and values.I dont know what is the problem with these codes

Here is my code

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 //The Android's default system path of your application database.

    public static String DB_PATH;

    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;
    public static String TABLE_NAME="pincode";

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 3);
        this.context = context;

        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = "pinnew1.sqlite";
        openDataBase();
    }


    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }

        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
      public HashMap<String, String> getPinDetails(){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                user.put("city", cursor.getString(1));
                user.put("state", cursor.getString(2));
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            // return user
            return user;
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Comment: Have you check the file permissions? Are you able to connect to another table? It's possible you have got the path to the database wrong, as SQLlite will generate a new database file, if one doesn't exist. Therefore it sounds like you have got the file path wrong.